# $location.url and $scope.$apply = Cannot read property '$$nextSibling' of null

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

We have a service handler that changes the location. The location does not change until something else triggers a digest. So, I used $apply, but getting errors from that.

```
$scope.myFunction = function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $location.url(path);
    });
};
```

Above gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$nextSibling' of null
```

From what I found, it seems like the $scope is getting destroyed during a phase cycle...But how can you use apply() on a location change without this error?

EDIT:

Testing to see if this scenario is related to our current app and discovered that reloading the route works oddly enough, which seems like a hack?

```
$scope.myFunction = function () {
   $location.url(path);
   $route.reload() 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Inject a `$rootScope` and use it instead of the `$scope`:

```
$location.url(path);
$rootScope.$apply();
```

The `$rootScope` will be available for the lifetime of the app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried that and error was still present... very odd.

Comment: Then, could you try running the `$rootScope.$apply()` on a separate line like in the edited answer?

Comment: Could you create a plunker or include more detail such as a full code around `myFunction()`?

Comment: tried to isolate here as much as possible, i've edited question with some findings around reloading the route